# How does one lookup of max value in matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a table that looks like this:

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  586  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  0  0  4  0  1  2  0
  637  0 0 0 0 0 0 2 3 2  2  0  4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
  989  0 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 0  0  0  2  1  0  0  1  2  1  0  3  0  2  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0
  1081 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  5  0  0  2  1  0  1  1  1
  2922 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  3  1  1  2  0  0  1  0  1
  3032 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0  0  1  0  2  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  3  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

Numbers 1 to 30 in the first row are my labels, and the columns are my items. I would like to find, for each item, the label with the most counts. E.g. 586 has 4 counts of 26, which is the highest number in that row, so for 586, I would like to assign 26.

I am able to get the maximum value for each row with max(table1[1,])), which gets me the maximum value for first row, but doesn't get me the label it corresponds to, but I don't know how to proceed. All help is appreciated!

dput:

```
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(6L, 30L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("586", "637", "989", "1081", "2922", "3032"), c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
    "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30")), .Names = c("", 
"")))
```

Comment: What is the desired structure of the output that you are looking for?

Answer (score 8):

`max.col` will give you vector of column numbers which correspond to maximum value for each row.

```
> max.col(df, tie='first')
[1] 26 12 20 22 22 8
```

You can use that vector to get column names for each row.

```
> colnames(df)[max.col(df, tie='first')]
[1] "26" "12" "20" "22" "22" "8"
```

Comment: sometimes just typing what you want to do (max in this case) in R console and hitting tab helps ;)

Comment: Same here. First I've seen of `max.col`... +1

Comment: Notice the different behavior w.r.t. tie breaking? Or was that some error in paste()ing?

Comment: More important:  how come there's no `max.row` ?  Yeah I know `max.col(t(mymat))` but it seems silly to provide one and not the other -- not to mention a `max.dim(my_array,along=1)` :-)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are looking for `which.max`. Assuming your matrix is called "temp":

```
> apply(temp, 1, which.max)
 586  637  989 1081 2922 3032 
  26   12   20   22   22    8
```

`apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (the second argument) will apply a function by *row*.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you, I will accept your answer in a few minutes, when I can!

Comment: beat me by 50 secs, I deleted my answer :D +1 for you!!

Comment: @Jilber, sorry! Just trying to get my SO quota in before I call it a night ;)